# PyMongo Insert excruciating slow data base with ~ 100M records

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I'm experiencing extremely slow inserts in a MongoDB  (roughly 200 sec/insert) and I'm not at all sure why.

I have a CSV file of anonymised usernames (ints), anonymised comment id (ints), and comments. All of this is read in as strings, but the first two fields could be cast to ints without any issue.

The database contains collection of 100M records, and right now am trying to build a mapping users with their comment IDs, which is written into another collection. 
There are roughly 60K users on which the 100M comments are distributed. That is build user_id = [comment_id0,...,comment_idN] for each user and insert that into the database for quicker fetching of all of a users comments.

```
def save_user_comments(dataset):
    usrs = defaultdict(list)
    updatebar = tqdm(total = 100000000, desc = 'Generating user-comment map', leave = False)
    pool = mp.Pool()

    for i, (user_id, comment_id, _) in enumerate(dataset):
        usrs[str(user_id)].append(comment_id)
        updatebar.update(1)

    prev = 0
    keys, vals = list(usrs.keys()), list(usrs.values())
    results = pool.map_async(write_user, zip(keys, vals)).get()

progbar = tqdm(total = 67377, desc = 'Users Inserted', leave = False )
def write_user(itempair):
    usr, comments = itempair

    db = MongoClient(host = some_ip, port = some_port).GenderSpectrum
    table = db.user

    if db.user.find_one({'user_id': str(usr)}):
        progbar.update(1)
        return

    u_obj = {}
    obj = db.data.find_one({'user_id': str(usr)})

    u_obj['comment_ids'] = comments
    u_obj['_id'] = str(usr)
    u_obj['is_female'] = obj['is_female']
    u_obj['user_id'] = str(usr)
    db.user.insert_one(u_obj)
    progbar.update(1)
    return 1
```

The only things I can see in this code that would slow it down is that a new connection is created for each insert. However, having tried with batches of 500 documents to be inserted using one connection (using both single and multi document insert) is even slower. So is running this code sequentially.

Does someone have a better suggestion?

MongoDB Version: v3.4.9

PyMongo Version: 3.5.1

Python Version: 3.5.3

OS: Ubuntu 17.4

Comment: I find it hard to believe that bulk insert could be slower than many `insert_one` running in serial, since the individual operations would involve much more overhead. That would imply the slow part of the code is not in the MongoDB side, but in another part. Likely the part where the new document is being created. Have you tried profiling using cProfile?

Comment: The bulk inserts ran with about 300s/iteration versus 200s/iteration for the individual. None of this makes sense to me. I did try profiling but nothing looked suspicious. I'm verifying that creating indexes helped (which it looks to have done).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The insert itself is likely very fast, it seems probable that some other part of your loop is slow. If "user_id" is not indexed, then this is probably the slow part:

```
db.data.find_one({'user_id': str(usr)})
```

Create an index on user_id in the "data" collection. Just do this once:

```
db.data.create_index([('user_id', 1)])
```

That may take a few minutes, after that the "find_one" will be much faster.

You also create a new MongoClient for each insert, which will slow your code down a bit, also. Create the MongoClient once for the duration of your program: declare it as a global variable, not a local variable in your "write_user" function.

Comment: The Mongo docs explicitly state that one should never create a global client but rather have one for each process. Creating indexes seems to have worked with speeding it up (did not realise you could do that!), I'll update this once I've verified that it did.

Comment: "One MongoClient per process" is correct - a process is a Python program. You create a process when you execute "python myscript.py". What your code shows is creating a MongoClient per function call, which is going to be slower than it should be. I recommend creating the MongoClient as a global variable so that it lasts the duration of your Python program.

Comment: Well if you look at [this](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#id21) they indicate that this is the preferred method, as in this case each process would a function call. I guess it would also be possible to create _n_ mongo instances which are then reused.